# How can I connect to Kovan using Ethereumj

Tags: ethereumj, kovan

I'm trying to connect to Kovan using Ethereumj based on the way that I used to connect to Ropsten. The sample example works, however when I try to do peer.discovery.enabled=true I'm not sure which IPs to put, and when I put static enodes it still doesn't work and therefore I'm not able to sync with the network.

I'm using this as the config :

```
peer.discovery = {
   enabled = false
}

peer {

active = [
    { url = "enode://c005dd308256c60fab247813d8bf6d6e81f9cd354287837eb1c2fcf294adaa913a3208e88900ef5c55a8cba7042c301d80503edec2ad3f92a72e241ee6743854@192.241.230.87:30303" },
    { url = "enode://85705212fd28ebdd56669fb55e958feb9d81f74fe76c82f867564b6c2995e69f596df0f588eba16f1a43b69ce06485d68231a0c83fed8469b41eba0e390c126f@139.59.146.42:30303" },
    { url = "enode://2aa81bd0a761cd4f02c934dcf3f81c5b65953e51ab5ba03ceb1f125eb06418a1cdffb1c9d01871aa7bd456f3fce35e745608189ad1164f72b2161634b0c3f6ea@188.166.240.190:30303" },
    { url = "enode://c5900cdd6d20795d58372f42dfbab9d664c27bb97e9c27972741942736e919122f9bac28e74cbc58e4ff195475ea90d9880b71a37af5b5a8cb41d843f765cff8@174.138.79.48:30303" },
    { url = "enode://48caeceb2724f2f71406990aa81efe87f8c53f26441d891473da2ae50cc138f238addc0e46b5aee240db55de8c711daac53d7b32a3f13e30edb86a3ca7c2700b@138.68.143.220:30303" }
]
}

peer.p2p.eip8 = true
peer.networkId = 42
sync.enabled = true 
genesisFile = main/resources/kovan.json
blockchain.config.name = ropsten 
database.dir = database-kovan
```

And this is the genesis file that i'm using (kovan.json) :

```
{
  "alloc": { },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000042",
  "timestamp": "0x00",
  "parentHash":     "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "extraData": "0x3535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535353535",
  "gasLimit": "0x5B8D80",
  "difficulty": "0x20000",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Comment: I don't think EthereumJ supports Proof of Authority yet.